# How can I use more than one vendor/autoload.php files - or how merge them? ( composer)

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I'm new on composer and I don't understand so much how is working.

I'm using composer on windows.

very easy installing and I don't understand more.

For example;

```
C>directory>php composer.phar
```

just all...

and there is giving in "vendor" directory "autoload.php" and Im requiring this and working on files.

It's good for me if working Im just one githup project.

For example I install with use composer "Guzzle 3.0" It's okey, working very well.

And I install on my Centos server MongoDB Driver with composer too. And it's working very well too.

But I need to merge them, I need to use them at same file .

And I don't understand how can I merge them ...

there is different directories and file name is same.

Could you show me way - solutions idea?

How can I use composer should be install at same time Guzzle 3 and MongoDB PHP Client?

Comment: Do you know how to install single package? If so, you can require more package in one directory. You will still use only SINGLE vendor/autolaod.php. Composer will "merge" install requirements for both for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution...

I create clean directory. And make it "composor.json" file and I write these codes inside and save.

{
    "require": {
        "guzzle/guzzle": "~3.9",
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.0.0"
    }
}

Then run to composer install... and installed all ...